# How can I edit and delete node in react-sortable-tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, fluent-ui

I have to do drag and drop tree view using react-sortable-tree. And also I need crud operations in my tree view. I have done to add, edit and delete into my parent node on tree view. Unexpectedly, I have some issues whenever I drag my node that time my first-child will edit and after that updated properly, but could not work delete functions, and also nth-child will not work properly to add, edit and delete node.

My [code sandbox live link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-moon-ht7hj?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are updating the state using old setState syntax. Like this,

`setState({ stateKey: stateValue });`

But new useState hook doesn't need the stateKey. You can update the state by just calling the `setState(stateValue)`.

So, instead of writing this,

```
settreeData({
      treeData: removeNodeAtPath({
        treeData: treeData,
        path: path,
        getNodeKey: ({ treeIndex: number, node: TreeNode }) => {
          return number;
        },
        ignoreCollapsed: false
      })
    });
```

You should write this,

```
settreeData(
      removeNodeAtPath({
        treeData: treeData,
        path: path,
        getNodeKey: ({ treeIndex: number, node: TreeNode }) => {
          return number;
        },
        ignoreCollapsed: false
      })
    );
```

Here is the working [code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-cannon-3pyw7?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thank you, it's working well to remove all parent and child nodes... And also need to update data when I clicked to edit data that data need to update that edited node... But, currently, I got an error at that time edited data to update the new parent node. pls clarify my issues... https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-goldberg-5g7nl my link

Comment: Update Tree Node Cannot Work Properly... New data to add well into parent... kindly help to clear that error... my live link... https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-glitter-himr8?file=/src